# Header in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to add a special header in Excel 2010. It's the one which you can scroll down on the Excel data and the header is always visible on top. And you can see in it in Normal View.

Actually, I think it's something like a panel or something; I don't really know what it is.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for Freeze Panes (View menu).